# All possible combinations of columns in dataframe depending on value in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, combinations

My `df` looks like this:

```
sent  token  token2
1     word1  word1
1     word2  word2
1     word3  word3
1     word4  word4
1     word5  word5
2     word6  word6
```

Now I want to get all possible combinations of tokens in a list if they have the same value for `sent`. The output should look like something like this:

```
[1, word1, word2, n]
[1, word1, word3, n]
[1, word1, word4, n]
[1, word1, word5, n]
[1, word2, word3, n]
...
```

I tried using `itertools` and `crosstab` consctructions but I can't seem to figure out how to add a condition to them.

Comment: What is `n`.. ?

Comment: It's just a useless column I forgot to add in the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `merge` here, then sort the value , drop the duplicated by using 
`np.sort` and `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.loc[:,['sent','token2']].merge(df.loc[:,['sent','token']],on='sent')
s[['token','token2']]=np.sort(s[['token','token2']],1)
s=s.loc[s.token2!=s.token].drop_duplicates()
s.head()

Out[213]: 
   sent token2  token
1     1  word2  word1
2     1  word3  word1
3     1  word4  word1
4     1  word5  word1
7     1  word3  word2
```